# StorageException has occurred. Unable to upload images in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

This code was working before i was able to change image and upload them in firebase but suddenly i am getting this error now , i dont know whats the problem seem to be.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int MAX_LENGTH = 100;
    private FirebaseUser mFireBaseUser;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
    private TextView display;
    private TextView c_status, id;
    private ImageView proPic;
    private Button changeStatus, changePic;
    private static final int GALLERY_PIC = 1;
    private StorageReference mStorage;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressBar;

    private DatabaseReference onlineDatabase;
    private FirebaseUser current;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        mFireBaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String uId = mFireBaseUser.getUid();
        mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(uId);

        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        mProgressBar = new ProgressDialog(this);

        display = findViewById(R.id.setting_displayName);
        c_status = findViewById(R.id.setting_status);
        proPic = findViewById(R.id.setting_image);
        changeStatus = findViewById(R.id.setting_changeStatusButton);
        changePic = findViewById(R.id.setting_changeImageButton);
        id = findViewById(R.id.setting_displayId);

        current = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        onlineDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(current.getUid()).child("Online");

        mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String name = dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString();
                String image = dataSnapshot.child("Image").getValue().toString();
                String status = dataSnapshot.child("Status").getValue().toString();
                final String thumbImage = dataSnapshot.child("Thumb_image").getValue().toString();
                String v_id = dataSnapshot.child("Id").getValue().toString();

                display.setText(name);
                c_status.setText(status);
                id.setText(v_id);

                if(!thumbImage.equals("default")) {
                    Picasso.with(SettingsActivity.this).load(thumbImage).placeholder(R.drawable.avatar_default).into(proPic);
                    }

                proPic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), FullScreenImageView.class);
                        intent.setType(thumbImage);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        changeStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, ChangeStatus.class));
            }
        });

        changePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent gallery = new Intent();
                gallery.setType("image/*");
                gallery.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(gallery, "SELECT IMAGE"), GALLERY_PIC);

            }
        });


    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        if(requestCode == GALLERY_PIC && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            CropImage.activity(imageUri)
                    .setAspectRatio(1, 1)   
                    .start(this);
        }

        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                mProgressBar.setTitle("Uploading Image");
                mProgressBar.setMessage("Please wait while we uploading the image and process...");
                mProgressBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                mProgressBar.show();

                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();  
                String uId = mFireBaseUser.getUid();

                File thumb_filePath = new File(resultUri.getPath());
                Bitmap thumb_bitmap = new Compressor(this)
                        .setMaxWidth(1000)
                        .setMaxHeight(1000)
                        .setQuality(1000)
                        .compressToBitmap(thumb_filePath);

                //for uploading thumb image to database

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                thumb_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                final byte[] thumb_byte = baos.toByteArray();

                StorageReference store = mStorage.child("Profile picture").child(uId + ".jpg");     // random() er bodole "uId" likhle valo hobe.
                final StorageReference thumb_store = mStorage.child("Profile picture").child("Thumb").child(uId + ".jpg");

                store.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){

                            final String download_url = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                            UploadTask uploadTask = thumb_store.putBytes(thumb_byte);

                            uploadTask.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> thumb_task) {

                                    String download_thumb_url = thumb_task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                                    if(thumb_task.isSuccessful()) {

                                        Map updateHashMap = new HashMap();      //    Map <String, String> likhle hobe na.
                                        updateHashMap.put("Image", download_url);
                                        updateHashMap.put("Thumb_image", download_thumb_url);

                                        mDatabaseReference.updateChildren(updateHashMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                    mProgressBar.dismiss();
                                                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                }
                                                else{
                                                    mProgressBar.dismiss();
                                                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                    else{

                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else{
                            mProgressBar.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception error = result.getError();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        onlineDatabase.setValue("true");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        onlineDatabase.setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
    }

}
```

This is my profile screen with a simple image view and two buttons only. When i try to change my profile image i get the following error.

```
    I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage:6
I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage, version >= 6
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000039/DynamiteModulesC_GmsCore_prodmnc_xhdpi_release.apk
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000039/DynamiteModulesC_GmsCore_prodmnc_xhdpi_release.apk
E/ChimeraFileApk: Failed to validate DexClassLoader.
                  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.chimera.DynamiteModuleInitializer" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/vendor/lib, /product/lib]]
                      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                      at ddb.loadClass(:com.google.android.gms@12673021@12.6.73 (040306-194189626):3)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                      at day.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673021@12.6.73 (040306-194189626):22)
                      at ddn.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673021@12.6.73 (040306-194189626):84)
                      at ddn.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673021@12.6.73 (040306-194189626):52)
                      at ddn.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673021@12.6.73 (040306-194189626):117)
                      at ddn.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673021@12.6.73 (040306-194189626):114)
                      at ryk.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673021@12.6.73 (040306-194189626):13)
                      at com.google.android.gms.chimera.container.DynamiteLoaderImpl.createModuleContext(:com.google.android.gms@12673021@12.6.73 (040306-194189626):18)
                      at ryf.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@12673021@12.6.73 (040306-194189626):12)
                      at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:499)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzed.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.zzk.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zzb(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.ace.<init>(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.ace.zzg(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzKO(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.firebase.storage.zzr.run(Unknown Source)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:776)
E/ChimeraModuleLdr: Failed to load code for module FileApk(/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000039/DynamiteModulesC_GmsCore_prodmnc_xhdpi_release.apk)
                    ddp: Failed to load code for /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000039/DynamiteModulesC_GmsCore_prodmnc_xhdpi_release.apk
                        at day.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673021@12.6.73 (040306-194189626):23)
                        at ddn.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673021@12.6.73 (040306-194189626):84)
                        at ddn.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673021@12.6.73 (040306-194189626):52)
                        at ddn.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673021@12.6.73 (040306-194189626):117)
                        at ddn.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673021@12.6.73 (040306-194189626):114)
                        at ryk.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673021@12.6.73 (040306-194189626):13)
                        at com.google.android.gms.chimera.container.DynamiteLoaderImpl.createModuleContext(:com.google.android.gms@12673021@12.6.73 (040306-194189626):18)
                        at ryf.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@12673021@12.6.73 (040306-194189626):12)
                        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:499)
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzed.zza(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.zzk.zza(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zzb(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zza(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zza(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ace.<init>(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ace.zzg(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzKO(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.zzr.run(Unknown Source)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:776)
W/ChimeraDebugLogger: Singleton logger instance not set.
E/DynamiteLoaderV2: Failed to create module context.
                    ddp: Failed to load code for /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000039/DynamiteModulesC_GmsCore_prodmnc_xhdpi_release.apk
                        at day.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673021@12.6.73 (040306-194189626):23)
                        at ddn.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673021@12.6.73 (040306-194189626):84)
                        at ddn.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673021@12.6.73 (040306-194189626):52)
                        at ddn.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673021@12.6.73 (040306-194189626):117)
                        at ddn.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673021@12.6.73 (040306-194189626):114)
                        at ryk.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673021@12.6.73 (040306-194189626):13)
                        at com.google.android.gms.chimera.container.DynamiteLoaderImpl.createModuleContext(:com.google.android.gms@12673021@12.6.73 (040306-194189626):18)
                        at ryf.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@12673021@12.6.73 (040306-194189626):12)
                        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:499)
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzed.zza(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.zzk.zza(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zzb(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zza(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zza(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ace.<init>(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ace.zzg(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzKO(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.zzr.run(Unknown Source)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:776)
W/DynamiteModule: Failed to load remote module: Failed to load remote module.
E/NetworkRqFactoryProxy: NetworkRequestFactoryProxy failed with a RemoteException:
                         com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$zzc: Remote load failed. No local fallback found.
                             at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zza(Unknown Source)
                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.ace.<init>(Unknown Source)
                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.ace.zzg(Unknown Source)
                             at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzKO(Unknown Source)
                             at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                             at com.google.firebase.storage.zzr.run(Unknown Source)
                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:776)
                          Caused by: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$zzc: Failed to load remote module.
                             at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zzb(Unknown Source)
                             at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zza(Unknown Source)
                             at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zza(Unknown Source) 
                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.ace.<init>(Unknown Source) 
                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.ace.zzg(Unknown Source) 
                             at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzKO(Unknown Source) 
                             at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source) 
                             at com.google.firebase.storage.zzr.run(Unknown Source) 
                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:776) 
E/UploadTask: Unable to create a network request from metadata
              android.os.RemoteException
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ace.<init>(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ace.zzg(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzKO(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.firebase.storage.zzr.run(Unknown Source)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:776)
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
                     Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
E/StorageException: null
                    android.os.RemoteException
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ace.<init>(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ace.zzg(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzKO(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.zzr.run(Unknown Source)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:776)
                    StorageException has occurred.
                    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
                     Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
                    null
                    android.os.RemoteException
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ace.<init>(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ace.zzg(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzKO(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.zzr.run(Unknown Source)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:776)
E/HW-JPEG-DEC: [HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete](3321): HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
E/HW-JPEG-DEC: [HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete](3321): HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
I/HwPointEventFilter: do not support AFT because of no config
```

build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.sarin.guff'
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.5.+'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.github.dimorinny:floating-text-button:0.0.4'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.3.0'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.willowtreeapps.spruce:spruce-android:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0'
    implementation 'hani.momanii.supernova_emoji_library:supernova-emoji-library:0.0.2'
    implementation 'com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions2:rxpermissions:0.9.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.zhihu.android:matisse:0.4.3'
    implementation 'com.github.mancj:MaterialSearchBar:0.7.6'
    implementation 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    implementation 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.hanks:passcodeview:0.1.2'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4"
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

project build gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/hani-momanii/maven"}
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

FIREBASE STORAGE RULE:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```