# Error in adding image to firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

I'm using kotlin/android and firebase storage, before when I wanted to upload an image to firebase storage it was working well. but recently I get error.
I search alot in stackoverflow and I found this question that is similar to mine but there was not any answer for that:

[StorageException has occurred. Unable to upload images in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50186722/storageexception-has-occurred-unable-to-upload-images-in-firebase?rq=1)

Here is my error:

```
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
 Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
StorageException has occurred.
An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
 Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: FirebaseStorage-Upload-1
    Process: com.example.bestplaceapp, PID: 20236
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getToken(Z)Lcom/google/android/gms/tasks/Task; in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.example.bestplaceapp-1/base.apk)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.Util.getCurrentAuthToken(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:148)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:65)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:57)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.sendWithRetry(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:457)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.beginResumableUpload(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:257)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:198)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:1106)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
     Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
```

my code was working before, here is my code:

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if(requestCode == GALLERY_ID && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){

        var image: Uri = data?.data!!
        // We crop the image
        CropImage.activity(image)
            .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
            .start(this)
    }

    if(requestCode === CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
        val result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data)
        if(resultCode === Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            // preparing image
            var resultUri = result.uri
            mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
            var userId = mCurrentUser!!.uid
            var thumbFile = File(resultUri.path)

            // We compress the image and save in thumbnail field in database
            var thumbBitmap = Compressor(this)
                .setMaxHeight(200)
                .setMaxWidth(200)
                .setQuality(65)
                .compressToBitmap(thumbFile)

            //We upload images to firebase
            var byteArray = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            thumbBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArray)
            var thumbByteArray: ByteArray
            thumbByteArray = byteArray.toByteArray()

            var filePath = mStorageRef!!.child("user_images")
                .child(userId + ".jpg")

            //Create another directory for thumbnail images ( smaller, compressed images )
            var thumbFilePath = mStorageRef!!.child("user_images")
                .child("thumbs")
                .child(userId + ".jpg")
            // end of preparing image

            // put main image file to firebase storage
            var uploadTask_MainImage = filePath.putFile(resultUri)

            uploadTask_MainImage.continueWithTask { task ->
                if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                    task.exception?.let {
                        throw it
                    }
                }
                filePath.downloadUrl
            }.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    val downloadUri = task.result.toString()

                    // put thumbnail image file to firebase storage
                    var uploadTask_ThumbnailImage: UploadTask = thumbFilePath
                        .putBytes(thumbByteArray)

                    uploadTask_ThumbnailImage.continueWithTask { task ->

                        if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                            task.exception?.let {
                                throw it
                            }
                        }

                    thumbFilePath.downloadUrl
                    }.addOnCompleteListener { task ->

                        var thumbUrl = task.result.toString()

                        if (task.isSuccessful) {

                            var updateObj = HashMap<String, Any>()

                            updateObj.put("image", downloadUri)
                            updateObj.put("thumb_image", thumbUrl)

                            //We save the download url of main image and thumbnail image to users table in database
                            mDatabase!!.updateChildren(updateObj)
                                .addOnCompleteListener { task: Task<Void> ->
                                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                                        Toast.makeText(
                                            this, "Profile image saved!",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                                        ).show()
                                    } else {
                                        // Handle failures
                                        // TODO
                                    }
                                }
                        } else {
                                // Handle failures
                                // TODO
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }

}
```

I use these storage rules and in my code the user should be login for saving image to storage:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please share your rules in firebase storage

Comment: Make sure you're using all the latest versions of the Firebase libraries in your build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

You must change your storage rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write; //<- Change here
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dear friend I found my problem, the version numbers of my firebase-storage was not compatible with the version of firebase-database and firebase-auth, I changed the verions in gradle.build file like this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
```

and it worked :)